# Must MSA be re-performed after annual instrument calibration?

Tags: computational-statistics, measurement, msa

I'm working in an automotive company that must follow [IATF](https://www.iatfglobaloversight.org/) (International Automotive Task Force) requirements.

I administrate a test-bench that performs radio frequency tests using an appropriate measure instrument.

IATF, before to start the production process the test-bench has been successfully validated using MSA (Measurement System Analysis) procedures.

After one year without changes both in process and test-bench measure chain the instrument must be calibrated and adjusted if necessary from the producer (calibration lasts one year).

Have I to re-perform MSA after the calibration of the instrument?

Facts are:

- the instrument is the same as before (same serial number) or is the same model (different serial number)
- the instrument is fresh calibrated (like when I performed the MSA first validation)

so, my opinion is that the measurement test chain is the same as before so I don't need to provide MSA documentation do auditors. The calibration + optional adjustment process don't modify the instrument, it restores the instrument to the conditions of the previous calibration.

I'm not able to find official IATF documentation or others sources about that: does calibration + optional adjustment procedure modify the measure process?

This is the calibration definition from the MSA AIAG manual:

> A calibration system is a set of operations that establish, under specified
>   conditions, the relationship between a measuring device and a traceable
>   standard of known reference value and uncertainty. Calibration may also
>   include steps to detect, correlate, report, or eliminate by adjustment any
>   discrepancy in accuracy of the measuring device being compared.

so, by definition, a calibration process is a check between instrument actual characteristics and nominal characteristics that comprises adjustments to align/restore  real and nominal characteristics. In any case after this process real characteristics are compliant to nominal

Comment: It would be wise to cross-calibrate the new and old instruments. This can either be done side by side with paired data, or it can be done (less desirably) by comparing tests on different cars (before instrument change, and after instrument change) to see if different results are obtained.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This is really an engineering question rather than a statistical one - we're not the right people to ask & we haven't enough information to gainsay your opinion in any case.

Comment: I don't think it's an off topic question. MSA is a specific tag of the community. Answers can refer to a "standard" MSA, I'll remove specific references to IATF.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - MSA is certainly on topic here, but whether or not the properties of the entire measurement process might change substantially from one calibration of the measurement instrument to the next depends on the particulars of the measurement process & instrument. Perhaps the only general argument that can be advanced is that *by design* a re-calibration shouldn't have repercussions elsewhere in the process, & should, as you say, closely match nominal to real characteristics.